# How to add input text in request parameter in form action

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf. I want to pass a parameter to endpoint when submitting a form, with the value of a text field.

This is my controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/students/page/{no}")
public String paginate(
    @RequestParam("keyword") String keyword,
    @PathVariable(value = "no") int pageNo,
    @RequestParam("sortField") String sortField,
    @RequestParam("sortDir") String sortDir, Model model
){
    int pageSize = 5;

    Page<Student> page = null;
    if (keyword == null) {
        page = studentService.paginate(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
    } else {
        page = studentService.searching(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortField, keyword);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
    }

    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studentList = page.getContent();

    model.addAttribute("currentPage" , pageNo);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
    model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());
    model.addAttribute("students", studentList);

    model.addAttribute("sortField" , sortField);
    model.addAttribute("sortDir" , sortDir);
    model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir" , sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");
    return "index";
}
```

```html
<form th:action="@{'/students/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?keyword=' + '&sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="50" th:value="${keyword}" class="form-control"/>
        &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

What I get is:

```
http://localhost:8081/students/page/1?keyword=nue
```

What I expect to get is:

```
http://localhost:8081/students/page/1?keyword=nue&sortField=name&sortDir=desc
```

Comment: This might help `https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls`

Comment: Add the other parameters as hidden inputs to your form.